# AttributeError: module 'blog.views' has no attribute 'post_detail'

Tags: django

File **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

File **views.py**

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from . import urls

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(
        published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Even though `post_detail` attribute has been included, still I get the error that it's not included. Can someone please help?
Edit:
As people suggested,tried removing the from . import urls line but still getting the same error.
Also attaching my html file if that helps:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
                    {% for post in posts %}
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="date">
                                <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What's your project structure? You have a circular import: you import `urls` in `views` and `views` in `urls`.

Comment: Yeah, that statement `from . import urls` looks wrong, or at least out of place. Does your code work without it?

Comment: Tried removing it,still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular import.

Your `views` module imports your `urls` module, and vice versa.

This means that neither file can finish importing.

You should remove this line from your `views.py`:

```
from . import urls
```

As you're not using it, this will have no adverse effect.